# How to create a vcproj to build boost 1.54 (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: boost

My application use boost 1.54 and it's not up to me to upgrade it. Now I have to port the whole thing to Visual Studio 2013 but I still can't figure out a proper way to build it. So, is there a way to make a vcproj that can be built with VS 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building boost basically is quite simple.
These guide lines describe the process:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html

Basically what you have to do is,

- Open a VisualStudio Command Prompt
- Change the current dir to your boost directory i.e:

  CD c:\myStuff\boost\boost_1_54_0\
- Call boptstrap:

  bootstrap
- start build i.e:

  bjam address-model=32

This is the process that worked for me with VC2010. It should work with 2013 as well. If you have problems specific to VC2013, please report the error messages you receive in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use BlueGo to build boost: 
[image]

BlueGo is a tool which builds Boost libraries using Visual Studio 2010/12/13. You just have to start the application, select your configuration and hit the Build button- everything else works automatically. The application downloads the library, extracts it and builds it.